# Drupal modules to display external RSS feed

Tags: views, 7, feeds

what Drupal modules should be installed and enabled to display external RSS feed? I mean not default Drupal Aggregator module, but another, more flexible way to display feed in any page as content. (I had all this preconfigured, but a long time ago)

Answer (score 1):

[Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) (previously FeedsAPI) is the one you want. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Import or aggregate data as nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple database records.
>
> - One-off imports and periodic aggregation of content
> - Import or aggregate RSS/Atom feeds
> - Import or aggregate CSV files
> - Import or aggregate OPML files
> - PubSubHubbub support
> - Create nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple database records from import
> - Extensible to import any other kind of content
> - Granular mapping of input elements to Drupal content elements
> - Exportable configurations
> - Batched import for large files